# How to Increment Value Atomically with Redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I have below code in `nodejs`:

```
const decrease = async (userId, points) => {
    const user = await redisClient.hgetall(userId);
    if(user.points - points >= 0) {
       await redisClient.hset(userId, userId, user.points - points);
    }
}
```

since `async/await` is not blocking the execution, if there are multiple requests for the same userId, the code is not running as atomically. That means the user points may be decreased multiple times even there is not enough point left on users account. How can I make the method run atomically?

I have checked redis `multi` command and it works for multiple redis statements. But in my case, I need to calculate the user points which is not part of redis command. So how to make them run as an atomic function.

I also read the INCR pattern: https://redis.io/commands/incr
But it doesn't seem to fix my issue. The patterns listed there need to work with expire which I don't have such requirement to give a specific timeout value.

Comment: Why is nodejs the first keyword that comes to your mind when you are clearly using REDIS. Seems a pretty obvious search: https://www.google.com/search?q=redis+atomic+increment and I wonder what the first search result might just be? Also tag your question to your real audience

Answer (score 3):

Use the power of (Redis) server-side Lua scripts by calling [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval). It should probably look something like this:

```
const lua = `
    local p = redis.call('HGET',KEYS[1],'points')
    local d = p - ARGV[1]
    if d >= 0 then
      redis.call('HSET', KEYS[1], 'points', d)
    end`
const decrease = async (userId, points) => {
    await redisClient.eval(lua, 1, userId, points);
}
```